# how to get value from ajax response in different textfields if there is more than one value in response?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

i create a program in which response is coming from ajax which have two values testcode and testname, I have three text fields in my jsp page , One is for testid, when i run program and enter testid value in first text field and press tab then ajax response is coming in which testcode ANd testname  is present.
but the problem is that in 2nd and 3rd text field both values(testname,testcode) are coming
together, i want a particular testname is go to particular field ,not both the values in same field.

code is:

### index1.jsp(jsp file)

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="a.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form  method="post" action="hi">
    test_id:<input type="text" name=testid onblur="mango1(this.value)">
    test code:<input type="text" name="testCode" id="tc">
    testName:<input type="text" name="testName" id="tn">

    <br><input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <div id="k"> no test name!</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### a.js(java Script)

```
function mango1(testid)
{
    alert("this is mango1 "+testid);

    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
    else
        {

        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            /*document.getElementById("k").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;*/
            var item=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("tc").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("tn").value=xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
            };
            /*xmlhttp.open("POST","hello?testid="+testid, true);*/
            /*xmlhttp.open("POST","hello?testid=", true);*/
            xmlhttp.open("POST","hi?testid="+testid, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

### hi.java (servlet for getting response from database)

```
package one;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import DAO.TestDao;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class hello
 */
@WebServlet("/hi")
public class hi extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public hi() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String testid=request.getParameter("testid");
        System.out.println("testid is "+testid);
        /*if(testid.equals("1"))
        {
            out.write("HIV");
        }
        else
        {
            out.write("Urinetest");
        }*/
        TestDao t1=new TestDao();
        Vector vec=t1.getName(testid);

    out.write((String) vec.get(0));

    out.write((String) vec.get(1));
    }

}
```

### testDAo.java (java file for database action)

```
package DAO;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;



//import beans.Test;

import DAO.DBCon;

public class TestDao {




    public Vector getName(String testid)
    {
        Connection con=DBCon.getConnection();
         System.out.println("got connection");

        Vector temp=new Vector();

        try
        {
            ResultSet rset=null;
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select testcode,testname from test where test_id=?");
            System.out.println("got control here");
            pst.setString(1,testid);

            rset=pst.executeQuery();
                 while(rset.next()){ 
                     temp.add(rset.getString(1));

                     temp.add(rset.getString(2));
                     System.out.println("got control here in loop");
                 }
                }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return  temp;       
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use separator between like

```
out.write((String) vec.get(0) + ",");

out.write((String) vec.get(1));
```

When you get response use split to split text and set to both fields like

```
var responseTextVar = xmlhttp.responseText;
var item=responseTextVar.split(',');
document.getElementById("tc").value=item[0];
document.getElementById("tn").value=item[1];
```

Comment: Fenil shah , sir its not working now ,(seprator) is also display in both the text fields

Comment: Did you get splitted text in "item"?

Comment: yes sir,in both item[0] and item[1] ,the same value is displayed in both fields with seprator(comma).

Comment: I think there should be problem with split, try me edited answer now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the completecode which work fine and this is very simple way

```
<%-- 
    Document   : viewtodata
    Created on : Apr 19, 2014, 12:41:27 PM
    Author     : sohail
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="uid" value="" id="uid" />
        <input type="text" name="pass" value="" id="pass"/>
        <input type="text" name="2nd" value="" id="2nd" />
        <input type="text" name="3rd" value="" id="3rd" />
         <input type="text" name="4th" value="" id="4th" />
         <input type="text" name="incen" value="" id="incen" />
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#uid").mouseleave(function(e) {
           // e.preventDefault();
            s = $("#uid").val();
           // z = $("#pass").val();
                $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "FromData?action=pass",
             data : "uid=" + s  ,
              //data : "name=" + s + "&age=" + z ,
             //"name" ye wo parameter name hy jo min nay controller mn req.getpara sy hasil krna hy or s and z mn value ja r hy

                success : function(data) {
                    $('#pass').val(data);
                }
            });
     //return false; 
     });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#uid").mouseleave(function(e) {
           // e.preventDefault();
            uid = $("#uid").val();
           // z = $("#pass").val();
                $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "FromData?action=vin",
             data : "uname=" + uid  ,
              //data : "name=" + s + "&age=" + z ,
             //"name" ye wo parameter name hy jo min nay controller mn req.getpara sy hasil krna hy or s and z mn value ja r hy

                success : function(data) {
                    $('#2nd').val(data);
                }
            });
     //return false; 
     });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#uid").mouseleave(function(e) {
           // e.preventDefault();
            price = $("#uid").val();
           // z = $("#pass").val();
                $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "FromData?action=price",
             data : "price=" + uid  ,
              //data : "name=" + s + "&age=" + z ,
             //"name" ye wo parameter name hy jo min nay controller mn req.getpara sy hasil krna hy or s and z mn value ja r hy

                success : function(data) {
                    $('#3rd').val(data);
                }
            });
     //return false; 
     });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#incen").mouseleave(function(e) {
           // e.preventDefault();
            incen = $("#incen").val();
           // z = $("#pass").val();
                $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "FromData?action=incen",
             data : "incen=" + incen  ,
              //data : "name=" + s + "&age=" + z ,
             //"name" ye wo parameter name hy jo min nay controller mn req.getpara sy hasil krna hy or s and z mn value ja r hy

                success : function(data) {
                    $('#4th').val(data);
                }
            });
     //return false; 
     });
    });
</script>       

  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.servlets.cal;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author sohail
 */
public class FromData extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */




       try { 
            String values=request.getParameter("action");
           if(values.equals("pass"))
            {
                String uid=request.getParameter("uid");
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ajaxdata","root","sohail");

String sql = " SELECT password FROM login WHERE userID = ? "; 
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
pStmt.setString(1, uid); 
//pStmt.setString(2, upass); 

ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(); 

String pass; 
if ( rs.next() ) { 
pass = rs.getString("password"); 

// creating a PersonInfo object 



// adding a beanto arraylist 
 out.println(pass);
} // end while 
       }// end of if *********************************************
           else if(values.equals("vin")){
           String uid=request.getParameter("uname");
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ajaxdata","root","sohail");

String sql = " SELECT vin FROM login WHERE userID = ? "; 
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
pStmt.setString(1, uid); 
//pStmt.setString(2, upass); 

ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(); 

String vin; 
if ( rs.next() ) { 
vin = rs.getString("vin"); 

// creating a PersonInfo object 



// adding a beanto arraylist 
 out.println(vin);
} // end while 
           }//end of vin if******************************
           else if(values.equals("price")){
           String pri=request.getParameter("price");
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ajaxdata","root","sohail");

String sql = " SELECT price FROM login WHERE userID = ? "; 
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
pStmt.setString(1, pri); 
//pStmt.setString(2, upass); 

ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(); 

String price; 
if ( rs.next() ) { 
price = rs.getString("price"); 

// creating a PersonInfo object 



// adding a beanto arraylist 
 out.println(price);
} // end while 
           }//end of price if **************************
            else if(values.equals("incen")){
           String incen=request.getParameter("incen");
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ajaxdata","root","sohail");

String sql = " SELECT price FROM incentive WHERE incentiveID = ? "; 
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
pStmt.setString(1, incen); 
//pStmt.setString(2, upass); 

ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(); 

String price; 
if ( rs.next() ) { 
price = rs.getString("price"); 

// creating a PersonInfo object 



// adding a beanto arraylist 
 out.println(price);
} // end while 
           }//end of incen if **************************
       } // end of 2nd try

catch(SQLException sex){ 
System.out.println(sex); 
} //end of catch
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FromData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FromData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```